# Clone multiple dropbox selected options and combined them in to 1 appendto

Tags: jquery, append, clone

I have multiple dropdowns and I'd like to combine the selected options of both dropdown + text and append that to a `<p>`.

I was recently able to code URL parameters to auto select certain dropdown options. This would be the reverse of that I guess. How to generate URL parameters from the dropdown options.

When the user makes their selection they can click the button (getshareinfo) which will auto generate the parameters and append it to the `<p>` below.

So far this is what I'm stuck on, I've tried adding text directly into the selector via '' and + but that doesn't seem work.

Example of what it should do:
Box 1: driving
Box 2: fast

generated URL text: [www.domain.com?user=driving&speed=fast](http://www.domain.com?user=driving&speed=fast)

```js
$('#getshareinfo').on('click', function() {
  $("#env-select option:selected").clone().appendTo("#shareinfo");
  $('#src option:selected').clone().appendTo("#shareinfo");
})
```

```html
<select id="env-select">
  <option value="driving">driving</option>
  <option value="biking">biking</option>
  <option value="walking">walking</option>
</select>
<select id="src">
  <option value="slow">slow</option>
  <option value="average">average</option>
  <option value="fast">fast</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="getshareinfo">Share</button>
<br>
<p id="shareinfo"></p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Edited**

Comment: I made you a  snippet. Please add relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: Please update the snippet with specific HTML referenced by the code to allow us to discern what is meant by "dropboxes "

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss updated sorry about that I ment ***dropdown***

Comment: FYI I formatted the HTML and remove an errant `</body>` from the middle of it - assumed a typo there from copy/paste

Comment: Technically it is a `<select>` not a "drop...anthing" but your update by adding the HTML makes that clear as we see that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the value?
Just do

```
$("#shareinfo").text( $("#env-select").val()+ $("#src").val())
```

to concatenate or if you need a URL

```
const url = new URL("https://www.example.com")
url.searchParams.set("user",$("#user").val())
url.searchParams.set("speed",$("#speed").val())
$("#shareinfo").html(`<a href="${url.toString()}">Click</a>`)
```

Comment: small typo's here `$("#user").val)` - I would edit but wanted you to be aware

Comment: I'm actually targeting the name of the option not the value because the value is being utilized to pass a file url. But pretty much this except I want to display what the url would be so that it can be copied.

Comment: the url this spits out is "https://www.example.com/?user=function%28a%2Cb%29%7Breturn+a%3Dnull..."? It labels the parameter's correctly but I quite literally need it to be user=<option name>

Comment: There was a typo, switched the .val to .text and got my answer, thank you!!!